# DTrace for Linux ustack() invalid address in action

Tags: linux, dtrace

When I run the following .d script with DTrace for Linux:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s
syscall::open:entry
{
    @[ustack()] = count();
}
```

I get many errors of the following kind:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2 (ID 320864: syscall:x64:open:entry): invalid address (0xfffd) in action #2
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2 (ID 320864: syscall:x64:open:entry): invalid address (0xfffd) in action #2
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2 (ID 320864: syscall:x64:open:entry): invalid address (0xfffd) in action #2
```

What should I do to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

You should try a later dtrace release. I believe this was fixed - the stack walk code had to keep on being rewritten due to erraticness of compilers, distros and 32 vs 64 bit kernels.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to Systemtap in the meanwhile. Took me ages to setup correctly but works OK now.

Comment: I'm still getting the error with the latest dtrace4linux. Is there some specific compiler/distro/kernel combination that is known to work?

Comment: I'm also get the same error on ubuntu with the build from the master. How can I provide more info to pinpoint the bug?